# For Wordpress, Is there a Twitter plugin shows twitter updates from people I follow?

Tags: twitter, wordpress

does anybody know if there is a Wordpress plugin that allows me to show Twitter updates from people I follow? If someone knows about it, please share with me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one will do what you need: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-friends-widget/

It says it's compatible up to 2.7 (not the latest, 2.8.4) but many of the 2.7 plugins work fine in 2.8 so it's worth a try. It was updated fairly recently and the author looks like he's still around.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would like to show my twitter friends tweets not just their avatars. The plugin shows just only avatar doesn't it? If I'm wrong, please let me know.

Comment: You're right, it only lists the friends, not their most recent tweets. I'm not sure if that's possible anymore, due to a restriction set by Twitter - see the third FAQ on this page for another Twitter widget that used to pull in friends' feeds: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-widget-pro/faq/